# Displaying Contents in the Web Page with out Save option

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Contents are in  text/image format more specifically a slide and it  has to be displayed in the web page when the end user  clicks the link.The contents are suppose to be open on the Next Tab or on the Same Tab. when User clicks the link.Mainly No Save  option should be there.

I have tried with PDF but couldn't restrict the user from save and print.
While trying it with HTML using Frames it does not meets the Browser Compatibility.

Suggestions and Idea's are Highly appreciated...

Comment: *"Mainly No Save option should be there."*  Not in my browser.  Not on my machine.  *"Suggestions and Idea's are Highly appreciated..."*  Don't be so protective of data.  If I wanted the data so badly, I could photograph the screen and put it through OCR.  If you don't trust the user with the data, don't give it to them in the first place.

Comment: if you use a ppt or pdf, the users will be able to download it..why dont you use simple images displayed one after the other on the webpage

Comment: To continue on @AndrewThompson's theme, if the data has been sent to the client's browser, they can definitely get it, no matter how much you try to hide or obfuscate it.  And by hiding it, you'll frustrate your users.

Comment: @Steve  Yes, that was a (far less colorful but) shorter way to put the point. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I'll play Hemingway to your Shakespeare. :)

Comment: @Steve  (laughs) No not Shakespeare, but I have [some of the Bard's plays](http://pscode.org/sp/) available for reading.  ;)

Comment: To Say, the contents are some course materials for the students.once it is uploaded to the server they shall only able to view it through their portal.